# Kivy: Sound starts to play, but is 'unstoppable' on Android, but on Windows it works

Tags: python, android, audio, kivy

I got a series of ToggleButtons in kivy, with each loaded with a different sound file. When I try my Code in Windows, everything works as expected, but on Android via the Kivy Launcher, the sound doesn't get stopped.

```
class AudioButton(ToggleButton):
    sound = ObjectProperty(None)

    def killsound(self, state, dt):
        self.sound.stop()
        if 'Click to stop' in self.text:
            self.text = self.text.strip('\nClick to stop')
            self.height = 60
        else:
            pass

    def on_press(self):
        self.bind(state=self.killsound)
        if self.state == 'normal':
            self.sound.stop()
        else:
            self.sound.play()
            self.text = self.text+'\nClick to stop'
            self.height=240
```

Here's what it does / should do:

- Create an `AudioButton` instance with a previously specified sound file (also specified: `size_hint`, `font_size`, and `group`(to act as radio buttons)
- `on_press` fires the callback `killsound` when the state of the Button changes
- When the Button is `state=='down'` the sound plays, and the Text of the Button gets a Caption appended
- If the Button is `state=='normal'` it stops the currently playing sound, if the concerning Button gets pressed, if another Button gets pressed, there's the Callback:

Callback(killsound):

- directly stops the sound when the state changes
- removes previously added Caption and resizes the Button

On Windows, everything works fine with this code.
On Android, however, when the `killsound` gets called, it removes the caption and resizes the Button, but it won't stop the sound - The old sound (which should be stopped) is still playing, and the new one starts, so I got both sounds playing at the same time, same with more than two sounds.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a different behaviour on windows and android, i would suggest opening an issue in the kivy tracker.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I just opened an issue. I'll update my Question if it get's resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This have been fixed in Kivy 1.4.1. You should talk to us via mailing list, or report a github issue instead of posting here :)